# What's "irit" in the E-types - Life song?

Tags: lyrics, european

The Song "Life" of the musician E-Type has following verse:

> You tell me 
> There's gonna be a showdown somewhere 
> It's irit

I looked up the word ***irit*** in the web but couldn't find anything that could explain its meaning. Does someone know it?

**Video is timed to verse in question**

Comment: I found a word that sounds similar but it is spelled differently, could it be up to the listener?

Comment: @Emil - What word did you find? I think these lyrics are incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that word is notated correctly, I don't hear any "t" sound at the end, and the sound at the beginning is closer to "eye" than to "ear," as you might expect if it was "irit."

My best guess is it's the word "irie," which is borrowed from Jamaican patois, and means "all right." It doesn't exactly match the immediate context, but it seems plausible in terms of the larger lyric.

Answer (score 0):

The only word I can come up with that fits is that "irit" is short for "irritating", which means

> causing displeasure, anger, or annoyance ([Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/irritating))